# itext writeSelectedRows doesn't ourput first time I print the document

Tags: itext

I have a header class that creates a header.  That header is output on every page.  If the document is a draft rather than final I need to add `DRAFT REPORT` in the header.
The `headerTable` text shows up every time.  The `draftTable` text does not show up the first time I create the document, but it does if I create the document again.

Does anyone know how to fix this or why it happens?  I have the following code:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
CustomPdfReport.incrementPageNum();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

String pgTitle = CustomPdfPage.getPageTitle();
if (null != pgTitle && !pgTitle.isEmpty()){
    Phrase pageTitle = getHeaderPageTitle(pgTitle);
    BaseResource baseResource = BaseResource.getInstance();
    String AppPath = baseResource != null ? baseResource.getStringValue(BaseResource.APPLICATION_PATH) : BaseResource.getString(BaseResource.APPLICATION_PATH);

    String imagePath = AppPath + "shared" + File.separator + "images"+ File.separator + "printTitleHeaderImage.jpg";

    try{
        logoImage = Image.getInstance(imagePath);
       } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("CustomHeaderFooter.onOpenDocument had an error seting up the image instance "+ e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

float [] imageScale = {50,50};
float width = PdfConversionFromInches.convertInchesToPageUnits(10.0);
float [] headerTableWidth = {80,20};
PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(2);
try{
    headerTable.setWidths(headerTableWidth);
    headerTable.setTotalWidth(width);
    headerTable.setLockedWidth(true);
    headerTable.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(topMargin);
    PdfPCell headerCell = PdfCell.createTextCell(pageTitle, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, pageColor);
          headerCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
          headerTable.addCell(headerCell);

         PdfPCell imageCell = PdfCell.createImageCell(imagePath, Element.ALIGN_TOP,   Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 1, imageScale, pageColor);
         headerTable.addCell(imageCell);
         headerTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(2,pageColor,PdfCell.BIGGER_STANDARD_CELL_HEIGHT));

         headerTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, leftMargin,  PdfConversionFromInches.convertInchesToPageUnits(8.5), cb);

//check for report being a draft report so we can put the DRAFT REPORT indicator on the page's header
         if (isDraftReport){
              PdfPTable draftTable = new PdfPTable(1);
              draftTable.setTotalWidth(PdfConversionFromInches.convertInchesToPageUnits(2.25));
              draftTable.setSplitLate(false);

              Phrase draftTitle = new Phrase(draftText,customFonts.getDraftFont());
              draftTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(draftTitle, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 3*PdfCell.STANDARD_CELL_HEIGHT, 1, pageColor));
              float height = 8.2f; 
              float xposition = document.leftMargin() + PdfConversionFromInches.convertInchesToPageUnits(7);
              draftTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, xposition,    PdfConversionFromInches.convertInchesToPageUnits(height), cb);
         }
        catch(DocumentException de) {
            LOGGER.debug("Custom HeaderFooter. An error occurred creating the header.  Error = "+de);
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);           
         }
```

Comment: This is probably unrelated to iText. If you add a `System.out` inside the `if (isDraftReport) { ... }` do you see anything printed to the `System.out`? If not, take a look at where and how you set the `isDraftReport` value.

Comment: Moreover, it's strange that you'd use a single-column, single-row table for something that can be easily added using a `ColumnText` object. By the way: using `setSplitLate()` doesn't make any sense when you use `writeSelectedRows()`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It was getting into the isDraft code, but the text was not set when expected.  The setSplatLate was a cut and paste error and I will be expanding the table.  Thanks for steering me in the right direction, it is working perfectly now.